# How to assign first gamepad for second player in local multiplayer [Unreal 5.3]?

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

How to assign gamepad for second player controller in local multiplayer [Unreal 5.3]?

Keyboard and gamepad automatically assign to player controller 0, so I need at least two gamepads to control the second player.

following does not work:

- skip assigning gamepad to player 1 does not work
- adding a delay seem to not work (a supposed workaround which i was reading about)
- . . .

I was researching in reddit, yt and the unreal engine forum and in the older version I just used "Skip Assigning Gamepad to Player 1", but since 5.1 it seems to not work anymore.